# Can be one device in multiple iOS Developer Program Account?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm developing an app and testing on devices under my iOS Developer Program Account but it will be released with another account. The client want to test the app in his device but using my account (he doesn't have account already and maybe I will not have access it it), so I need to register his device on my account. This device can be registred with another account at the same time, or if it can't be possible, if I remove it from my devices can be used in other account immediately?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can register a device to as many developer accounts as you like. Just beware that you can only register up to 100 different devices to 1 developer account per year.

Answer (score 4):

"You are allowed to register up to 100 iOS devices for testing and Ad Hoc distribution per membership year. Please Note: Although you may remove a device from your account, it will continue to count against your 100 device limit." [Here](https://developer.apple.com/support/account/) you can find help to implement this.

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

As for your question, I have the same devices connected with multiple accounts, so it's not a problem to do so.  The only **"limitation"** is what I've listed above.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a device with multiple accounts. Also, one account can have a max of 100 devices registered simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

"You are allowed to register up to 100 iOS devices for testing and Ad Hoc distribution per membership year.

How many iOS devices can I register for testing and Ad Hoc distribution?

You are allowed to register up to 100 iOS devices for testing and Ad Hoc distribution per membership year. Please Note: Although you may remove a device from your account, it will continue to count against your 100 device limit.

Can I use the Apple ID associated with my iOS Developer Program to join the iOS Developer Enterprise Program?

No. You must set up a new Apple ID to join the iOS Developer Enterprise Program.

What are the requirements for developing with the iOS SDK and Xcode?

To develop with the iOS SDK and Xcode, you must have an Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard or later and you must be registered as an Apple Developer.

As a Registered Apple Developer, what do I have access to in the iOS Dev Center?

As a Registered Apple Developer you have access to the latest version of the iOS SDK and the related resources and information available in the iOS Dev Center.

For access to the tools and information necessary to test apps on devices, you will need to join either the iOS Developer Program, the iOS Developer Enterprise Program, or both.